# Best approach to communicate between Fragment/Activity and RecyclerView.Adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My fragment:

```
public  class FragmentSort extends Fragment {
  @BindView(R.id.sortRecyclerView)
  RecyclerView sortRecyclerView;
  protected RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

  @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View rootView = inflater.inflate(layoutResId, container, false);
       adapter = new StoreListItemAdapter(getActivity(), collection);
       sortRecyclerView.setAdapter((RecyclerView.Adapter) adapter);
       return rootView;
}

     @Subscribe
public void onStoreClickEvent(Store store) {
    Debug.d(TAG, "onStoreClickEvent: store = " + store);
    handleFilterItemSelect(store.getAddress());
 }
}
```

Here my custom adapter:

```
public class StoreListItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<?> data = new ArrayList<>();

  public DataBindingRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<?> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
  }

  public void onClick(Store store) {
    EventBus.getDefault().post(store);
  }
}
```

When click on some item in list then call method `onClick`().
So I need my fragment to handle click of item.
To to do this I use EventBus.
After click I call

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(store);
```

And as result in fragment call method:

```
onStoreClickEvent(Store store)
```

So this is my model to communicate between my custom fragment and my custom adapter.

It's work. Fine.

The quesion is: Is this a best approach for communicate between fragment and adapter?

P.S. My custom adapter can use by fragment, activity or custom view.

Comment: there is no best approach. It is opinion-based, and therefore - off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: I see no purpose of that Event class. Why can't you just pass the store object itself?

Comment: You are right, I can send only Store object. Thanks. I update my post.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to create a listener interface like this:

```
public interface OnStoreItemClickListener {

    public void onStoreItemClicked(Store item);    

}
```

Then, in your Adapter, you declare a field of type `OnStoreItemClickListener` and you create a setter method for it.

When you detect a click, you simply check if your listener is set and call the `onStoreItemClicked()` method.

You can register a listener via the setter from wherever you need.

Comment: I think EventBus is more elegant sotution then create callback interface.